# iPhone : How do I drag or move UIImage/UIButton as shown below?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I dont know How to get following type of functionality in my app.

[image]

As shown in above figure user can slide(drag) different image parts and user can assemble image.

Can any one tell me which control is this ? Or any tutorial for it ?

Comment: I am thinking this is something more suited for a library like cocos2d, not UIKit.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII : Can you give me more details for coocs2d ? or link?

Comment: are you sure that this can only be possible by cocos2d ?

Comment: No, not 'only possible' - @RichardJ.RossIII said 'more suited' - you can do it with UIKit if you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the MoveMe sample app. It will show you how to allow movement of subviews by touch and drag.

You can then create imageViews for each of your puzzle pieces that can be moved around.

Once you have accomplished this you need to check during movement of a piece to see when it gets close enough to it's correct spot in the puzzle so it can snap into place when then user lets go of the piece.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: +1 for best possible fit of an example app. MoveMe also was the first thought I had when reading the question.

Answer (score 1):

That all depends on the kind of implementation you want to do.
It can be UIImageView,UIbutton etc.
The advantage with UIIMageView could be you can easily implement UIGestureRecognizer to move the views..

Answer (score 1):

For an app I built I used the touches functions:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event 
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

for dragging UIImageViews around.  Then you can use the CGRectContainsRect or CGRectContainsPoint to detect if the puzzle piece is in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about UIKit,
this could be a UIImageView with images having partial transparent areas.

Comment: UIKit would be bad because it's not made for games or things similar to games. I guess it'd be best to use OpenGL for this

Comment: OpenGL is the best one to use for games and perhaps the harest of all to use...atleast for beginners. COCOS2D will be perfect to start off with 2D games development.

Answer (score 0):

This is not that easy. You need to write the code first for how to move the image views. There are a lot of samples in Apple references.  Then you need to get the boundaries of each image to do this.

Comment: Thats great !! can you send me samples on dshah3888@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

My first attack on this problem would be as follows:

(1) subclass UIImageView to hold each piece of the puzzle.

(2) Customize your UIImageView subclass by initializing it with a UIPanGestureRecognizer. Something like:

```
self.panRecognizer = 
  [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget: self 
    action: @selector(handlePan:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer: 
  self.panRecognizer];
```

(3) In the action method associated with the pan gesture recognizer, update the object's location based on messages from the puzzle piece's pan gesture recognizer. Something like the following ought to work:

```
-(void) handlePan: 
  (UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
  UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = 
    (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender;
  if (panRecognizer.state == 
        UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
      panRecognizer.state == 
        UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
  {
    CGPoint currentPoint = 
      self.center;
    CGPoint translation = 
      [panRecognizer translationInView: 
        self.superView];
    self.center = CGPointMake
      (currentPoint.x + translation.x, 
        currentPoint.y + translation.y);
    [panRecognizer setTranslation: CGPointZero 
      inView: self.superView];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code how to move imgTest which is an UIImageView. Tested, work like a charm.

```
[[self imgTest]setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

//Save the first touch point
CGPoint firstTouchPoint;

//xd,yd destance between imge center and my touch center
float xd;
float yd;

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* bTouch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([bTouch.view isEqual:[self imgTest]]) {
        firstTouchPoint = [bTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[bTouch view]center].x;
        yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[bTouch view]center].y;
    }
}

{
    UITouch* mTouch = [touches anyObject];
    if (mTouch.view == [self imgTest]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];
    }
}
```

[source](http://www.exampledb.com/objective-c-touch-move-drag-and-drop-object-uiimageview.htm)